# Community Wiki: what triggers an Answer to become owned by CW?

Tags: support, community-wiki

What triggers the 'ownership' of a single-authored Answer to be transferred to Community Wiki?

Comment: Could you link to the answer, please?

Comment: I think I found the answer in question. I've removed the wiki status, and undeleted the answer. I also deleted the duplicate answer.  In the future if you have a problem with a post, please flag it for moderator attention, or ask a question here (as you did) but don't take any action yourself until the issue is resolved.  Thanks.

Comment: thank you, and my apologies for the hassle I caused.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Three ways that I'm aware of. You can do it to your own posts by checking the "community wiki" box when answering yourself. Moderators can toggle this on for anyone's posts. And there's also an automatic trigger when there are too many edits to a question (at last check 10 edits would trigger this, but it's possible for SE to modify the thresholds and algorithms without me knowing).

Comment: Hmmm ... Could have been any of those three, though I've never seen the 'community wiki box' so that would have been accidental, and I've been the only editor of my Answer so that seems unlikely.  I'm disappointed to see that I'll no longer receive reps considering all the time and thought I put into helping that user with quick replys to his comments and new information.

Comment: I suspect it's the last one if you're asking about [this question](http://diy.stackexchange.com/posts/27578/revisions), that's way more than 10 edits.

Comment: I believe SE's logic behind the CW on edits is to keep someone from making lots of minor changes to keep bumping their answer to the top of the active list to solicit votes.